# Hide tr (table row) with text content

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to hide a table row with javascript and css.
I have to admit that I'm still a beginner, so it's likely that I'll ask some stupid questions.

I want to hide a table row that somewhere in a td contains the text 'banana'.

Hopefully someone can help me out, thanks!

I've tried different kinds of code I found on the internet, but can't get anything working. This is what I got so far.

```
if(document.getElementsByTagName('tr').contains('banana')) 
{ 
   document.getElementsByTagName('tr').style.display = 'none'; 
}
```

Comment: `tr` elements contain `td` not text.....you should be searching for a `td` containing "banana".

Comment: We'll be able to help you better if you give a more complete example. For example, include a basic HTML example, with corresponding javascript that attempts to do what you. Also, when you say "can't get anything working" what goes wrong? Is there an error? What happens instead?

Answer (score 1):

Problem you have is you seem to be thinking in terms of jQuery. JQuery does loops under the hood. Since you are not in jQuery world, you need to do the loops yourself over the collection.

1. Select the rows
2. loop over the rows
3. Read the text
4. Check if text as match
5. if it does, hide it

```js
// select all the rows
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
// loop over the rows
rows.forEach( function (row) {
  // get the text of the row
  var text = row.textContent; // case insensitive use .toLowerCase()
  // see if it is in the string
  if (text.includes('banana')) {
    // add class to hide the row
    row.classList.add('hidden')
  }
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>apple</td><td>$1.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>pear</td><td>$1.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>banana</td><td>$1.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>strawberry</td><td>$1.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

How will this fail? When the text joins between cells there is no whitespace so you can make matches that are not there. Is you search for something that is partial sting in another word that can also be wrong.

Other option you have is instead of looping over the rows, you loop over the cells. And if there is a match in the td, you hide the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting `tr` element you can get all `td` element and perform the following:

```js
var tdcollection = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i = 0; i < tdcollection.length; i++) {
  if (tdcollection[i].innerText.indexOf("banana") >= 0) {
    tdcollection[i].parentElement.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>banana</td><td>test1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>grape</td><td>test2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, I changed your code to a runnable Code Snippet. I used the button `[<>]` that exists in the Answer editor toolbar.

Comment: Thanks , I will follow in future when i am submitting code